# Change the value of EditText with onClick Button?

Tags: android, function, button, textview, android-edittext

In main.xml I made a row containing a TextView, an EditText and a "+" and "-" button.

Underneath that I made an "Add" button that will help you create a new row When you click the add button, you get an EditText and a Submit and Cancel button.

On "Submit" it outputs the EditText value to the TextView and creates the same row as the first one.

The numeric value "NewValueBox" should +1 when the "+" button is pressed.
But because I call it in another function it is not recognized by createNewAddButton() function in which the button is set up.

So in short:
"How do I change the value of NewValueBox when I click NewAddButton?"

Here's the code:

```
package com.lars.MyApp;

import com.google.ads.*;
import com.lars.MyApp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DrinkRecOrderActivity extends Activity {

    int currentValue1 = 0;
    int currentValueNew = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText firstValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstValue);
        Button valuePlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valuePlus);
        Button valueMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valueMinus);

        final Button addValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

        final TableLayout tableLayout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        final LinearLayout addValueRow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addValueRow);

        final EditText addNewValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addNewValue);
        final Button submitNewValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitNewValue);
        final Button cancelNewValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelNewValue);

        // BEGIN ONCLICKLISTENERS
        valuePlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plusValue();
                firstValue.setText("" + currentValue1);
            }
        });

        valueMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                minValue();
                firstValue.setText("" + currentValue1);
            }
        });     

        addValue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addValueRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        cancelNewValue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addValueRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        submitNewValue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tableLayout1.addView(createnewRow());
                addValueRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addNewValue.setText("");
            }
        });

        // END ONCLICKLISTENERS

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }

    public TableRow createNewRow() {
        final TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        final EditText addNewValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addNewValue);
        newRow.addView(createNewTextView(addNewValue.getText().toString()));
        newRow.addView(createNewValueBox());
        newRow.addView(createNewAddButton());
        newRow.addView(createNewMinusButton());
        return newRow;
    }

    public TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);
        return textView;
    }

    public EditText createNewValueBox() {
        EditText NewValueBox = new EditText(this);
        NewValueBox.setHint("0");
        NewValueBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        return NewValueBox;
    }

    public Button createNewAddButton() {
        final Button NewAddButton = new Button(this);

        NewAddButton.setText("+");

        NewAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plusNew();

                //NewValueBox.setText("" + currentValueNew);
            }

        });

        return NewAddButton;
    }

    public Button createNewMinusButton() {
        final Button NewMinusButton = new Button(this);
        NewMinusButton.setText("-");
        return NewMinusButton;
    }

    // BEGIN PLUS AND MIN FUNCTIONS

    public void plusNew() {
        if (currentValueNew <= 999) {
            currentValueNew = currentValueNew + 1;
        }
    }

    public void plusValue() {
        if (currentValue1 <= 999) {
            currentValue1 = currentValue1 + 1;
        }
    }

    public void minValue() {
        if (currentValue1 >= 1) {
            currentValue1 = currentValue1 - 1;
        }
    }

    // END PLUS AND MIN FUNCTIONS

}
```

Comment: in the on-click-handler function for your button, call setText('chars') on the particular EditText object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ID`s for your `Views` so you can later reference them. Make 3 private static int field in your activity(the `ID` for *NewValueBox*, `NewAddButton` and `NewMinusButton`):

```
private static int edt = 1;
private static int add = 1001;
private static int minus = 2001;
```

Then in your `createNewValueBox()` method set the ID:

```
NewValueBox.setId(edt);
edt++;
```

Do the same for the `NewAddButton` and the `NewMinusButton`:

```
NewAddButton.setId(add);
add++;
```

---

```
   NewMinusButton.setId(minus);
   minus++;
```

Then in your listener for the buttons find out exactly which add button has been clicked and set the text in the corresponding `EditText`:

```
NewAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plusNew();
                int tmp = v.getId();
                EditText temp = (EditText) findViewById(1 + (tmp - 1001));
                temp.setText("" + currentValueNew);
            }
```

Kind of hackish method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!
Only thing I got now... When I add more than one row, and for example I press "+" 3 times. And then press the other value once it goes to 4.
So currentValueNew is counting on...

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk you should have a separate array to hold the newvalues because you are sharing that field with all the rows you add i think.

Comment: Yeah I figured, is there a way to do the same thing you did in v.getId(); to the array? So I counts the number of arrays or something?

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk you can't use `getId()`, that method exists only in the class `View`. This changes should help you solve the problems with the new: value http://pastebin.com/CkFWGtdB .

Comment: Okay, thank you for all your effort, a lot! 
But I still don't have it working with your example. 
In the NewAddButton we use this: temp.setText("" + currentValueNew); but in the plusNew() we don't do anything with the currentValueNew... I tried: temp1.setText("" + holdValues); but that does not work either.
Hope your not bothered with me yet. Again thank you for the effort

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk I forgot about that. The line should be: `temp.setText("" + holdValues.get(tmp - 1001));`

Comment: Thank you big time, I'm so glad it finally works, been messing with this minor thing to long